# storing an object with localStorage without JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to save a user's information using localStorage or anything that works really. I don't know a lot about localStorage but I figure in order to store an object in it I would need a function in the object maker. Perhaps I'm wrong, but that's why I'm posting.

I think that you can use localStorage.username(this.username) to store username but I need to now how to store an entire object without using JSON stringify. 
localStorage.newPlayer()

[JSfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/evbrf4pm/)

```
function Player(username, lvl, exp, expNeeded, nextLevel, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
    var self = this;
    this.username = username;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.nextLevel = nextLevel;
    this.expNeeded = expNeeded;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.fullLife = hp;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def = def;
    this.spd = spd;
    this.implement = function() {
        $('#user').text(this.username).addClass('playerName').data('player', self);
        $('#username').text("Username: " + this.username);
        $('#lvl').text("Level: " + this.lvl);
        $('#exp').text("Experience: " + this.exp);
        $('#expNeeded').text("Experience Needed: " + this.expNeeded);
        $('#gold').text("Gold: " + this.gold);
        $('#hp').text("HP: " + this.fullLife);
        $('#attack').text("Attack: " + this.atk);
        $('#defense').text("Defense: " + this.def);
        $('#speed').text("Speed: " + this.spd);
        $('#nextLevel').text("Next Level: " + this.nextLevel);
    };
    this.implement();
}
if($('body').attr("id") == "Home") {
    var newPlayer = new Player(prompt("What is your username?"), 1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 2, 1, 1);
}
playerEl = $('.playerName');
player = playerEl.data('player');
```

If you need to see the full code let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem. Is there anything unexpected? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why `JSON.stringify(new Player())` is not acceptable?

If you can't use JSON, you'd simply need to store each name/value pair into `localStorage` separately and get them out separately OR build a custom string of your own to place in `localStorage`, but `JSON.stringify()` is really the best fit for your scenario.

I think you just need to remove this from the Player function:

```
this.implement = function() {
    $('#user').text(this.username).addClass('playerName').data('player', self);
    $('#username').text("Username: " + this.username);
    $('#lvl').text("Level: " + this.lvl);
    $('#exp').text("Experience: " + this.exp);
    $('#expNeeded').text("Experience Needed: " + this.expNeeded);
    $('#gold').text("Gold: " + this.gold);
    $('#hp').text("HP: " + this.fullLife);
    $('#attack').text("Attack: " + this.atk);
    $('#defense').text("Defense: " + this.def);
    $('#speed').text("Speed: " + this.spd);
    $('#nextLevel').text("Next Level: " + this.nextLevel);
};
this.implement();
```

**So that the player can be serialized into a JSON object that can then be set into localStorage.**

That code would then be moved down into your `if` statement's true block and references to `this` would be replaced by your `newPlayer` object instance.

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LqgLxr0r/5/

[image]

Comment: It still breaks when I switch pages. I need the variable to be stored and be able to be called on another page, is there a different way to do that?

Comment: You need to explain what "breaks" means. My fiddle shows the object being set in localStorage, so you'd just need to use `var player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("player"));` on the next page.

Comment: after hitting ok on promp on home page I get http://prntscr.com/agl5qw if I go to battle page after this i get http://prntscr.com/agl678 sorry for not giving details but I've never worked with JSON or localStorage and really don't know what you need to know to figure it out.

Comment: The problem is likely unrelated to storing json in localstorage.

Comment: @Shniper Whatever issues you are having are not related to the actual data being stored properly. If you look at the screen shot I provided, you can not only see the data on the web page, but you can see the object stored in localStorage with that data. The problem is most-likely that now that the data has been stored a certain way, your code that goes and gets it is incorrect. Please post that code.

Comment: here is home page https://jsfiddle.net/eg8bweeL/ and here is battle page which is breaking https://jsfiddle.net/24wv10c9/ thank you for having the patience to help me out by the way

Comment: I'll take a look. But have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7hLLL54/1/ which first sets the data into localStorage and then gets it back out to display on the page.

Comment: @Shniper Yes, I've taken a look and the problem is that you are not getting the player back out of localStorage properly. See this corrected fiddle of yours: https://jsfiddle.net/u0vhfz0a/1/

Comment: @Shniper And, on the other page, the problem is the same. You have to access the parsed JSON object as with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxewhg7z/2/

Comment: how would I make both pages work without needing seperate js files? I added everything you had in the battle one to the intro one but that doesn't work.

Comment: In your .js file, make two functions, one that saves the data and one that gets the data. Based on an `if` decision, call the appropriate one as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9wcmuah/1/  That fiddle doesn't work though because I don't know what your criteria for saving vs. getting is, but it shows what you'd need to do.

Comment: storing things with javascript is seriously confusing. I guess I need to read up on a bunch of tutorials, thanks for helping

Comment: It's really not. First, when you have data to store, you store it with `localStorage.setItem(nameForTheData, theActualData)`. Then, when you need the data you go get it with `localStorage.getItem(nameForTheData)`. You have to decide when the set vs. get operation needs to take place, but by putting each operation into its own function, it's just a matter of calling the right one at the right time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106661/discussion-between-shniper-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: @ScottMarcus please join my chat when you have the chance

Answer (score -1):

```
//global function

Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
  }


//page 1 code 

//your data
 var arrayObj = [{
    name: 'user4',
    userid: '1111',
    msg: 'hello world!'
  }, {
    name: 'user2',
    userid: '2222',
    msg: 'hello universe!'
  }];







    localStorage.setObject('userInfo', arrayObj);

// page 1 code ends here


// page 2 code

    if (window.localStorage) {

        var $val = localStorage.getObject('userInfo', arrayObj);
    }

// returns $val =   [{name: 'user4',userid: '1111',msg: 'hello world!'}, {name: 'user2',userid: '2222',msg: 'hello universe!'}];
```